# How to convert a hex string to a uint8_t array? (C language)

Tags: c, type-conversion, hex, uint8t, uint8array

how can I convert a hex string to a uint8_t array?
My string is `02012B1530A6E3958A98530031902003876940000000000CDF9844173BE512AFFFFFFE11DBBA1F00079387800E13012E11FC017FFFFFFFFE39C10F40`
and I want to convert it into this array:

```
uint8_t array_uint[] = {0x02, 0x01, 0x2B, 0x15, 0x30, 0xA6, 0xE3, 0x95, 0x8A, 0x98, 0x53, 0x00, 0x31, 0x90, 0x20, 0x03, 0x87, 0x69, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0xDF, 0x98, 0x44, 0x17, 0x3B, 0xE5, 0x12, 0xAF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x11, 0xDB, 0xBA, 0x1F, 0x00, 0x07, 0x93, 0x87, 0x80, 0x0E, 0x13, 0x01, 0x2E, 0x11, 0xFC, 0x01, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x39, 0xC1, 0x0F, 0x40};
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sscanf()` to convert 2 bytes at a time from the source string into the destination array:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

size_t convert_hex(uint8_t *dest, size_t count, const char *src) {
    size_t i;
    int value;
    for (i = 0; i < count && sscanf(src + i * 2, "%2x", &value) == 1; i++) {
        dest[i] = value;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Note however that this approach may be inefficient, with a quadratic time complexity, on architectures where the standard library computes the length of the source string for each call to `sscanf()`. Using an intermediary array solves this problem:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

size_t convert_hex(uint8_t *dest, size_t count, const char *src) {
    char buf[3];
    size_t i;
    int value;
    for (i = 0; i < count && *src; i++) {
        buf[0] = *src++;
        buf[1] = '\0';
        if (*src) {
            buf[1] = *src++;
            buf[2] = '\0';
        }
        if (sscanf(buf, "%x", &value) != 1)
            break;
        dest[i] = value;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Storing the conversion result directly into the `dest` array is easy:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

size_t convert_hex(uint8_t *dest, size_t count, const char *src) {
    char buf[3];
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < count && *src; i++) {
        buf[0] = *src++;
        buf[1] = '\0';
        if (*src) {
            buf[1] = *src++;
            buf[2] = '\0';
        }
        if (sscanf(buf, "%hhx", &dest[i]) != 1)
            break;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Purists may argue that `%hhx` expects a pointer to an `unsigned char` instead of a `uint8_t` so the format should be `"%"SCNx8` or `"%2"SCNx8`, defined in `<inttypes.h>`, but these alternatives are less readable and unnecessary as type `uint8_t` is always identical to type `unsigned char` on architectures where it is defined.

Comment: thank you so much! do you know how to print the uint8_t array? if I do printf("%d", myarray[0]) it prints the decimal value of the first element of myarray. how can I print the exact element (0xFF, for example)?

Comment: @WonderWhy: decimal and hexadecimal are just representations of the *exact* value... Use `printf("0x%02X", myarray[0])` to get a hex representation with a `0x` prefix. Remove the `0x` to get the 2 hex bytes only.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to learn is that decimal, hexadecimal or even octal are just how the *binary* numbers stored in the computer memory are presented. Once you store the bytes in your array, they aren't really hexadecimal anymore.

Now for how to solve your problem: You need to extract two characters at a time, then convert each character to the corresponding integer value, and use bit-shirt and bit-or to combine them into a single byte value.

Converting the digits `0` to `9` into their corresponding value is easy, since the C specification say that they must be encoded contiguously (i.e. `'0'` must come right before `'1'` and so on). That means you can use simple subtraction with `'0'` to get the numeric value (`'0' - '0' == 0`, `'1' - '0' == 1` etc.).

The letters `A` to `F` are harder through, because there are many different possible encodings, including some that doesn't place letters contiguously. With that said, the most common encoding ASCII *do* is doing that, which means on most system you can use the same "trick" as for the decimal digits.

Then how to combine them, the first value needs to be shifted up (to the left) by four bits, and then bitwised OR'ed with the second value.

The result of that should be a single byte whose value is the same as the two hexadecimal digits from the string. Append this value to the array.

Comment: Probably my question wasn't clear at all, and I'm sorry for this. I only need to excract to characters at time from the string and put it into the uint8_t array. For example, my empty array is uint8_t myarray = {}, I excract "02" from the string and I add them to myarray, that will be myarray ={ 0x02 }

Comment: The standard C function strtol might be helpful, but you will then use a temporary zero-terminated string to which you copy two characters at a time.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
char data[] = "02012B1530A6E3958A98530031902003876940000000000CDF9844173BE512AFFFFFFE11DBBA1F00079387800E13012E11FC017FFFFFFFFE39C10F40";
char *p = data;
```

first byte is

```
(hexdigit(p[0]) << 4) + hexdigit(p[1])
```

You can loop the above expression with

```
do {
    uint8_t value = (hexdigit(p[0]) << 4) + hexdigit(p[1]);
    p += 2;
} while (*p);
```

for all the values (make sure `data` has an even number of characters).

The function `hexdigit()` (implementation is left as an exercise) converts `'0'` to `0`, `'1'` to `1`, ..., `'a'` to `10`, `'A'` to `10`, ...